# Single Notification for multiple Foreground Services using startForeground() call

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I have an app that has two services.

One is for showing UI for floating (overlay) on other apps using `WindowManager`. The other is for Location Tracking using `GooglePlayAPI`. My app always runs these services.

I want these services not to be killed by the OS. So I call `Service.startForeground()`. However there are two notifications in the notification drawer.

Is there a way to use a single notification for both services?

Comment: Two notification in android means?

Comment: @Pramod when use startForeground method in Service, android system sets notification about Service that running now. i use two services. and use startForeground method in both classes.

Comment: One option is to consolidate the 2 services into a single service.. I know this doesn't answer the question. But it may be an option for you given both services start and stop together.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I am facing the same...

Answer (score 38):

Yes, it is possible.

If we take a look at Service.startForeground() signature, it accept both notification id & the notification itself ([see documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))). Hence, if we want to have an only single notification for more than one foreground services, these services must share the same notification & notification id.

We can use the singleton pattern to get the same notification & notification id. Here is the example implementation:

**NotificationCreator.java**

```
public class NotificationCreator {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1094;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Foreground Service Channel";
    private static Notification notification;

    public static Notification getNotification(Context context) {

        if(notification == null) {

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("Try Foreground Service")
                    .setContentText("Yuhu..., I'm trying foreground service")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .build();
        }

        return notification;
    }

    public static int getNotificationId() {
        return NOTIFICATION_ID;
    }
}
```

Thus, we can use this class in our foreground services. For example, we have MyFirstService.java & MySecondService.java:

**MyFirstService.java**

```
public class MyFirstService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startForeground(NotificationCreator.getNotificationId(),
                NotificationCreator.getNotification(this));
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MySecondService.java**

```
public class MySecondService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startForeground(NotificationCreator.getNotificationId(),
                NotificationCreator.getNotification(this));
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Just try to run these services. Voila! You have a single notification for multiple foreground services ;)!

Comment: If you use RemoteViews to define the notification layout, you will still have the problem...

Comment: how should i stop foreground notification for both service at same time?

Comment: @Ajay Ideally you would have some other parent class (such as an Activity) start both of these Services, and also call stopService() on both of them when appropriate (such as onDestroy of the Activity, or a button click on the Activity's View to stop all Services). I hope that helps.

Comment: How many foreground services we can run simultaneously ?