# Same notification for multiple foregorund services, and keep the notification if any of them is stopped

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service

I'm creating an app that uses two foreground services:

- One for getting the Location
- The other to updload it to a server (every 30secs)

I'm currently testing my app with a device running Nougat but I'd like to make it Oreo-ready.

First I was using a different Notification for each foreground service, but then I wanted to try using the same notification for both, as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40101134/2597775).

If I stop any of those services by calling **stopService(intent)** then the notification disappears even if the other foregroundService is still running.

Is there a way to keep the notification even after stopping one of the services?

Then, when both services are down I will manually remove the notification

### EDIT added code as requested

This is how my services looks like (they are basically identical):

```
public class TrackingService extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    startForeground(getNotificationId(), getNotification(this));
    // Some other tracking/server stuff 
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Some other tracking/server stuff
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopForeground(false);
}
```

I'm starting them with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackingService.class);
    startService(intent);
```

And then stopping with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackingService.class);
    stopService(intent);
```

I've read that calling `stopService(intent)` will also remove that service from the foreground. So the calling to `stopForeground(false)` is redundant, but I leave it anyway.

And the singleton for the Notification is:

```
public abstract class SingleNotificacion {
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1999;
private static Notification notification;

public static Notification getNotification(Context context) {
    if(notification == null) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.settings_status_on_summary))
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        notification = builder.build();
    }

    return notification;
}


public static int getNotificationId() {
    return NOTIFICATION_ID;
}

public static void cancelNotification(Context context){
    ((NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
}
```

I've also try setting `onGoing(true)` and 'autoCancel(false)' when creating the Notification with no luck

Comment: Interesting question. Unfortunately my two Services (based on the code in the linked post but with some modifications -> notification channels, Kotlin, implemented onStartCommand() and return START_STICKY ) behave nicely and so I'm unable to reproduce your error (testing with an emulator running Oreo). Please share enough code for a [MCVE]